# Do I need my Time Machine backup if I copied my home directory to an external drive?

Tags: time-machine, restore

MacBook running slow. I want to do a wipe, clean install (OS X Yosemite) and restore.  I've copied my home directory to an external drive and could transfer it back after clean install.  I'm also doing a Time Machine backup to the external drive.

1. Do I need the Time Machine backup? This step is taking a long time.
2. Will installed software be restored simply by copying my home directory back after the clean install?
3. If this is the first Time Machine backup done on this computer, will there be any difference between copying the home directory and restoring from Time Machine? (I wouldn't want to restore the system, only the user files).

Comment: Backing up your home directory only copies the files that live in your home directory. Applications (generally) do not. So no, to your second question. Restoring your home directory on a clean install could also cause the problems to continue, because a lot of items (preference files, caches, etc.) are stored there that can cause a system to run slow if there is a problem with them. The idea of a clean install is to start clean, not to restore large chunks of what was previously there.

Comment: That helps.  So, clean install: then bring in only the files I need?  Is there a way to bring back selected installed softwares?
  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: install it again, is safest.